# How to check all variable are same in multi lined Array in Flutter?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, mobile-development

Hello I am new to Flutter, I am fetching array from JSON like below and I would like to check if every "value" = "";

```
"food_table": [
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "key": "aaa",
  "value": ""
},
{
  "name": "bbb",
  "key": "bbb",
  "value": ""
},
{
  "name": "cccc",
  "key": "cccc",
  "value": ""
},
{
  "name": "dddd",
  "key": "dddd",
  "value": ""
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question itself.

You can use `List.every` method for this, like this.

```
var jsonData = { "food_table": [/* all items */] }; // assuming this is your full data
bool everyValueIsEmpty = jsonData["food_table"]
      .every((item) =>item["value"] == "");

print(everyValueIsEmpty); // Will print true
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are having a `List` you can use the method [every](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/every.html).

```
final List<Map<String, String>> foodTable = [
    {"name": "aaa", "key": "aaa", "value": ""},
    {"name": "bbb", "key": "bbb", "value": ""},
    {"name": "cccc", "key": "cccc", "value": ""},
    {"name": "dddd", "key": "dddd", "value": ""}
  ];

final bool empty = foodTable.every((food) => food['value'] == "");
print(empty); // Prints true
```